# Data structure for a sparse matrix where elements are randomly distributed

Tags: c, data-structures, matrix, sparse-matrix

I couldn't think of anything else except a linked list.. Any better idea?

Comment: LCYSoft: It's not necessary that you add `C, ...` to your questions' titles; that's what the tagging system is for.

Comment: So what does this have to do with C anyway?

Comment: As I commented in your last question, you can use existing code.

Comment: What are you planning to do with your matrices ? This will put constraints on what libraries / algorithms are available to you.

Comment: I want to prepare for future interviews.. I know I can use existing code but I just want to practice myself c coding skill and sparse matrix seems like pretty challenging..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're storing elements in a matrix, you may want to consider using a hash table from coordinates to their contents.  This lets you look up the contents of any matrix location much more quickly than if they were stored in a linked list (namely, O(1) rather than O(n)).

Comment: Except that you cannot compute anything meaningful in reasonable time with a hash table approach. I wouldn't eg. multiply matrices which are stored in a hash table.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  My understanding is that it should be fairly easy to do a multiply with a hash table.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: two issues: 1) matrix multiplication is still O(n^3) with a huge constant: for CRS for instance, you can do most operations in O(nz) where nz is the number of non zero entries 2) data locality is important for matrices, typically elements of the same row are stored consecutively.

Answer (score 2):

[Quatree matrices](http://shimi.webzdarma.cz/vyzkum/memics08/quad.pdf) (the code used in the paper is [there](http://shimi.webzdarma.cz/vyzkum/quad/quad.html)) have reasonably good insertion and access complexities, and reasonably good performance. There are specific algorithms for them (mostly in form of research papers). However they are not really widespread. But they *do* deserve more love. If you intend to solve systems, a decomposition well suited to quadtree matrices is explained [there](ftp://www.cs.indiana.edu/pub/techreports/TR357.pdf).

If your matrix will be constructed at once, and you don't need to add/remove elements after it is constructed, then Compressed Row Storage (or compressed column storage) is widespread and efficient, and there are libraries and specific algorithms for dealing with them.

After all, you did not tell us what you want to do with your matrices.

Answer (score 0):

For every non-zero element you need to store its coordinates (row/column) and its value. There is a variety of ways to do that.

Wikipedia has an overview of a bunch of approaches: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix

It is impossible to say what's best for your application without knowing more about the sizes and density of your matrices, memory constraints, expected access patterns and so on.